# To use init or not to in Python classes

Tags: python, class, init

I have always defined variables for classes like:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
```

However, I discovered it is also simply possible to use:

```
class A():
    x = 1
```

In both cases, a new instance will have a variable x with a value of 1.

Is there any difference?

Comment: Try doing that with something like a list. See if you can spot the difference.

Comment: In first code snippet x is an instance member, in second it's class member.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For further reading, in the [Python Tutorial chapter on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), that matter is discussed in detail. A summary follows:

There is a difference as soon as non-immutable data structures take part in the game.

```
>>> class A:
...   x = [1]
... 
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a1.x.append(2)
>>> a1.x
[1, 2]
>>> a2.x
[1, 2]
```

In that case, the same instance of x is used for both class instances. When using `__init__`, new instances are created when a new A instance is created:

```
>>> class A:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x = [1]
... 
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a1.x.append(2)
>>> a1.x
[1, 2]
>>> a2.x
[1]
```

In the first example, a list is created and bound to `A.x`. This can be accessed both using `A.x` and using `A().x` (for any `A()`, such as `a1` or `a2`). They all share the same list object.

In the second example, `A` does not have an attribute `x`. Instead, the objects receive an attribute `x` during initialization, which is distinct for each object.

Comment: So pretty much in the simpler case, a list would be shared among all instances of the class? That really puts you to think... Did you ever specifically use it to share a list among instances?

Comment: @PascalvKooten You could do that, really depends on the use case whether it makes sense. I cannot recall having done it specifically with a list or any other mutable data structure. This doesn’t mean I did not do it though.

Comment: Nice, I'm happy I asked, it's nice to know something like this exists!

Comment: Try inspecting the `__dict__`s of `A`, `a1` and `a2` to see where `x` is being stored and what happens when you assign to it via `A.x = ...` or `a1.x = ...`. Basically, assigning to `a1.x` will cause `a1` to store something for `x`, which hides the `x` field of its class. When `x` holds a mutable object, you would probably not perform such an assignment and so you end up working with an object that's shared across all instances.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very imprecise. You speak about "variables for classes", but later you say "instance will have a variable". In fact, your examples are reversed. *Second one* shows a class A with a variable x, and the *first one* shows a class A with no variable x, but whose every instance (after `__init__`, unless deleted) has a variable x.

If the value is immutable, there is not much difference, since when you have `a=A()` and a doesn't have a variable x, a.x automatically delegates to A.x. But if the value is mutable, then it matters, since there is only *one* x in the second example, and as many xs as there are instances (zero, one, two, seventeen,...) in the first one.